# Missing group entry in gshadow

Tags: systemd, group

I recently installed ArcoLinux (Arch), but I am not familiar with a lot of the core linux functionality. I noticed that the service `shadow.service` failed.

The following is the output of `systemctl status shadow.service`:

```
● shadow.service - Verify integrity of password and group files
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/shadow.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-01-27 13:15:38 CET; 5min left
TriggeredBy: ● shadow.timer
    Process: 326 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/pwck -r || r=1; /usr/bin/grpck -r && exit $r (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 326 (code=exited, status=2)

Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 sh[333]: add group 'audio' in /etc/gshadow? No
Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 sh[333]: no matching group file entry in /etc/gshadow
Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 sh[333]: add group 'users' in /etc/gshadow? No
Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 sh[333]: no matching group file entry in /etc/gshadow
Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 sh[333]: add group 'nopasswdlogin' in /etc/gshadow? No
Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 sh[333]: no matching group file entry in /etc/gshadow
Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 sh[333]: add group 'autologin' in /etc/gshadow? No
Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 sh[333]: grpck: no changes
Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 systemd[1]: shadow.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jan 27 13:15:38 mpc5 systemd[1]: shadow.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I gather from this that there are some groups which are missing from `/etc/gshadow` which do in fact exist in `/etc/group`. I have not made any direct changes to either of these files.

Is this a cause for concern? Should I add these groups?

Comment: I dont know archlinux well, so cannot explain why gshadow is missing entries. It might be due to some badly written package that partly failed its installation. However, you should probably run `sudo grpck` and interactively fix the missing entries (reply 'y' to add group). I dont think it is serious.